# Descriptive complexity theoretic-characterizations of P and NP

Tags: computational-complexity

Prompted by Vinay Deolalikar's purported proof of P != NP, I've been reading up on Descriptive Complexity for some background material.

The major successes of Descriptive Complexity include Fagin's result that $NP=SO\exists$ (that is, the class NP is equal to the class of models of a second-order existential query over some vocabulary), and also that $P = FO(LFP)$ (that the class P is equal to the class of models of first-order queries that might use a Least-Fixed-Point operator), and also $PH = SO$.

My understanding of mathematical logic is quite shaky, but from what I understand, second-order formulas are not expressible in first order logic - how does this fact stand in relation to the results I mentioned above? Why does it not separate NP from P, or PH from P?

Comment: The elements of P and NP are _sets_ of models.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that this is finite model theory and it is quite different from logic on infinite structures, e.g. satisfiability of first-order formulas on finite structures is $\Sigma_1$, whereas the same question is $\Pi_1$ for general structures (where the formula is satisfiable iff it does not lead to (i.e. prove) contradiction).

It is not known yet if the properties of the **finite structures** expressible in SO are different from those expressible in $FO(LFP)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that clarifies much. But, what did you mean by "whereas the same question is in Pi_1" - what same question?

Comment: Thank you. I was referring to satisfiability of a formula over general (i.e. not necessary finite) structures. If we are given a first-order formula, it has a model iff it is consistent (by completeness theorem for first-order logic), and this is $\Pi_1$ property: $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff $\forall \pi, \pi is not a proof of \varphi \vdash \bot$.